# Do app code support only to put one kind of file?

Tags: asp.net, .net, app-code

Do app code support only to put one kind of file, i mean either c# class or vb class?
Because if i put both sort of file and create an object then, application throws error.
How can i make App code compatible with both.

Comment: What error do you get? you should be able to use C# libraries with Vb.net libraries, but they cant be in the same Project. they have to be 2 different assemblies

Comment: If you put C# and vb files into the same project/assembly, it doesn't compile. Is that what you want to say?

Comment: You can simply create two projects, one VB, on C#. One of them is a class library and then can be referenced and used from the other project.

Comment: What do you mean by app code?

Comment: Please try to put more effort into formulating your questions!

Comment: I assume he's referring to the 'app code' folder in an Asp.Net project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a single assembly or project you can only have one kind of source code, although you may reference multiple assemblies (of different languages) within the same project.